# Xamarin Forms: Call Command of ViewModel from DataTemplate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, datatemplate

I am stuck on a binding problem here.

I created a bindable layout which is inside a control template:

```
<ContentView x:Name="SettingsMenu" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">               
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">                   
        <StackLayout x:Name="SettingsStack" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SettingsSelectorTemplate}" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />           
    </ScrollView>        
</ContentView>
```

What I want to do is call a command inside the view model. The call is inside a item template selector as a resource dictionary inside App.xml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PlaceholderSettingsTemplate">
        ### SOME STUFF
     </DataTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderSettingsTemplate">
             ### SOME STUFF
         <Grid ...>
             <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ButtonClick" Command="{Binding BindingContext.SettingsTap, Source={x:Reference SettingsPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />  ########## <--------- WHAT TO USE FOR SOURCE?
             </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
     <data:SettingsSelector x:Key="SettingsSelectorTemplate" Placeholder="{StaticResource PlaceholderSettingsTemplate}" Heading="{StaticResource HeaderSettingsTemplate}" Content="{StaticResource ContentSettingsTemplate}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Before I moved it inside a resource dictionary in the App.xml file, I simply used the x:Name of the Parent Contentview. But: I can't reference it by name anymore because I moved it into a resource dictionary inside App.xml.

Now, the answer may be trivial but I just can't find a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `SettingsStack` StackLayout using the data template's Grid which wraps all the content. Since the `SettingsStack` has the same binding context as the parent content view, you can access the binding context in App.cs like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderSettingsTemplate">
    <!--### SOME STUFF-->
    <Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Parent.BindingContext.SettingsTap, Source={x:Reference ParentGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ParentGrid`'s parent is `SettingsStack` on your current page.

Answer (score 4):

From the item template (even if it's in a different file), you can access the view model of it's ancestor, using the following:

```
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type SettingsViewModel}}, Path=SettingsTap}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

In this case I just assumed that the name of the ancestor's view model is **SettingsViewModel**, but you get the point.

Here is an interesting article regarding relative binding, that describes other scenarios as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor

Cheers.

Comment: In my situation, the immediate parent wasn't going to work. Your answer set me down the right path. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

In another way we can use `ContentPage` as `AncestorType` directly. Then bind command with `BindingContext`.

```js
{Binding BindingContext.SomeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}
```

Complete example

```xml
<DragGestureRecognizer
    DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.SomeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
    DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Also this way works with separate resource files (eg. *MySeparateResource.xml -> MyPageView.xaml*).