# How to properly bind to VM Properties from within a DataTemplate

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, mvvm, datatemplate

**Problem:**

I have a page with a `ListView` to display a list of objects. I separated the `DataTemplate` to it's own file as per Microsoft's [Creating a DataTemplate with a Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating#creating-a-datatemplate-with-a-type). I want to be able to edit or delete entries in this list, so I have been using the `ViewCell`'s `ContextActions` `MenuItem` to provide this functionality. This worked up until I had to separate my DataTemplate from the `ContentPage`. The commands for handling editing and deleting reside in my `ContentPage`'s `BindingContext`, which is the `ViewModel`.

**Things I've Tried**

Multiple formats of binding, both `FindAncestorBindingContext` and `FindAncestor` `RelativeSource` Modes, and multiple kinds of `AncestorType`

```
{Binding BindingContext.EditCommand, Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}
{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestorBindingContext, AncestorType={x:Type views:LoginView}}, Path=EditCommand}
{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:LoginVM}}, Path=BindingContext.EditCommand}
```

**Question:**

**How would I bind to the commands in my `ViewModel` from the detached `DataTemplate`?** I have tried to use `RelativeSource` binding but the command is never triggered, or the ancestor is never found. Here is my basic setup:

ContentPage (LoginView):

```
....
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <vm:LoginVM x:Name="viewmodel"/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
<ContentPage.Content>
     ....
     <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="30" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
          <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding sessionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" HasUnevenRows="True" >
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                            <templates:LoginSessionTemplate/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
             </ListView>
        </Frame>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

DataTemplate:

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PIM.View"
          x:Class="PIM.DataTemplates.LoginSessionTemplate">
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:LoginView}}, Path=EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Edit"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
....
```

The bindings between template and data object are fine, I am only having troubles binding to the `ViewModel` from within the detached `DataTemplate`. Using the code above does not trigger the command. The context menu appears and the text for the buttons is correct, however the command is either never executed or the `ViewModel`'s `BindingContext` is never found. So far my only solution is to include the `DataTemplate` in the `ContentPage`, which really defeats the purpose of separating the `DataTemplate` in the first place. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Update & Answer**

ToolmakerSteve was kind enough to link a thread, and although the linked answer did not work, the accepted answer for the thread did. For some reason `FindAncestor` is not working in my case and I have to reference the `ViewModel` through the XAML hierarchy. I'm not sure if this is good practice for MVVM, but it is working.

**TL;DR:**

To reference your `ViewModel` from within a detatched `DataTemplate`, you must traverse the XAML heirarchy. To do this, give your `DataTemplate`'s `ViewCell` an `x:Name` parameter and then use the reference in your bind. The bind will access the `ViewCell`'s parents. The bind should look something like this:

```
{Binding Parent.Parent.BindingContext.MyCommand, Source={x:Reference ViewCellName}}
```

I only needed to change the `DataTemplate`

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PIM.View"
          x:Class="PIM.DataTemplates.LoginSessionTemplate"
          x:Name="VC">
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Parent.Parent.BindingContext.EditCommand, Source={x:Reference VC}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Edit"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
....
```

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744782/199364) which finds BIndingContext from the ContentPage.

Comment: Using `ContentPage` as the `AncesetorType` did not work either.

Comment: Rather than edit an answer into your question, you should post it as an answer, or edit your existing answer to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion made by @ToolmakerSteve in the comments didn't help, however the same thread's actual answer did. I was able to bind to my `ViewModel` by referencing the `ViewCell`'s parent(s) instead of using `FindAncestor`.

You must give your `DataTemplate`'s `ViewCell` an `x:Name` parameter in order to reference it. Next is to figure out how far up the heirarchy you must traverse before you reach an element that has the `BindingContext`
object you are looking for. In my case, I chose to go up two levels the first time and it worked. Here is my modified binding, where `VC` is my `ViewCell`'s `x:Name`.

```
{Binding Parent.Parent.BindingContext.EditCommand, Source={x:Reference VC}}
```

I find it odd that `FindAncestor` will not work in this situation. Perhaps it is a bug? Either way, thank you for the help.